# Java Multithreading: Does the thread on which an objects method is executed depend on the thread on the thread in which it is created?

Tags: java

Does the thread on which an objects method is executed depend on the thread on  the thread in which it is created?

Imagine you have two threads in your java applications Thread1 and Thread2 and two classes ClassA and ClassB.

You create an ObjectOfClassA on Thread1 then you create and ObjectOfClassB on Thread2, the ObjectOfClassB contains a reference to the ObjectOfClassA. When the ObjectOfClassB runs a method of ObjectOfClassA on which thread will the method be executed?

In you answer please provide a link to the relevant documentation.

Based on what I've seen I get the sense that the execution of an objects method is completely orthogonal to the thread on which it was created, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You create an ObjectOfClassA on Thread1 then you create and ObjectOfClassB on Thread2, the ObjectOfClassB contains a reference to the ObjectOfClassA. When the ObjectOfClassB runs a method of ObjectOfClassA on which thread will the method be executed?

On the same thread which is running the caller method of ObjectOfClassB itself (that would be Thread2 I guess... but as @Andrzej noted, it can be another, third thread too). This is completely independent of which thread created which object. What matters is only whether or not a given object is *published* (i.e. made available) to a given thread. If it is, it can be run by that thread.

Comment: ...and of course, if you have a completely separate third thread calling `b.foo(a)`, the method will be executed in that third thread.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle, indeed, thanks. I added further explanation to elaborate this point.

Comment: Is "publishing" an object in java the same thing as holding a reference to an object? I have never heard this term before.

Comment: @tjb, "Publishing an object means making it available to code outside of its current scope, such as by storing a reference to it where other code can find it, returning it from a nonprivate method, or passing it to a method in another class." - from [*Java Concurrency in Practice*](http://jcip.net/) ch. 3.2.

Answer (score 7):

There is no such thing as auto-thread-switching, so each method invocation happens on the 'current thread' no matter on which thread the object has been created.