# Threading and observer pattern in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, observer-pattern

Suppose I have two classes, Main class and Worker class

```
class Main implements StateChangeListener extends JFrmame{

   public void notifyMe(State state){
        //Change the GUI according to the state
   }  
}


class Worker extends Thread{
    public StateChangeListener listener;
    public void run(){
        listener.notifyMe(state);
    }
}
```

My question is:
Suppose worker is run in another thread, which thread will run the function **notifyMe()**?
The Main thread or the worker thread? Thank You

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Multithreading: Does the thread on which an objects method is executed depend on the thread on the thread in which it is created?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243492/java-multithreading-does-the-thread-on-which-an-objects-method-is-executed-depe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function call is executed under the control of a thread who called it. In your case since you are calling notifyMe() from the worker thread, the worker thread will be responsible for executing the method **notifyMe()**.

You can test this using `Thread.currentThread().getName()` to print the name of the Thread. See the getter/ setter for Thread name at [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/).

Answer (score 1):

The same thread which is running the worker.

Comment: ... except if the guy never managed to start the thread and just called `run()`. @Bear can you show us the code you use to start the thread?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, it will still be the thread which is running `Worker`.

Comment: I'm trying to second-guess the reason why this is asked. If Worker is not started, then arguably noone is running Worker (depends on what exactly you mean by "running the Worker").

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, yeah, could be, although nothing in the OP refers to `notifyMe` not being called... but of course, incomplete or vague questions may occur on SO (a few, occasionally :-P )

Comment: If the main thread executes the equivalent of `new Worker().run()`, the method will be called -- from the main thread.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, Why someone will call the run() method of a Thread directly ? I have not seen such a horrible code in my life so far ......

Comment: @rahul Lucky you, then :) It's actually a typical beginner's mistake.

Comment: @rahul Sorry, I don't understrand...
What's wrong about new Worker().run()? I am a newbie haha

Comment: @Bear The new thread is not started until you call `start` on it. The class `Thread` is itself just a handle, it is not a "thread". Just like `File` -- if you have a `File` object, that doesn't mean that the file actually exists. When you call `Thread.start`, a new thread starts and begins executing the `run` method -- it's just like that thread's `main` method. Note also that it isn't true that the `start` method calls `run` -- nobody calls `run`, just like nobody calls `main`. It's the starting point.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik oh, I see. Actually, I call start() instead of run(). Thanks for you guys :)